# how to read and write MP3 to database

Tags: c#, sql, mp3

how to  read MP3 from Sql database. in sql i have stored the file as binary format. now i want to retrive the Mp3 file stored in the sql and show in my aspx page. how????

pls help...

Comment: What do you mean by 'show'? Play it? Download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its simplest form this is how you would get the raw bytes, can't really show any more without knowing what you want it for...

```
private byte[] GetMp3Bytes(string connString)
{
   SqlConnection conn = null;
   SqlCommand cmd = null;
   SqlDataReader reader = null;

   using (conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
   {
      conn.Open();

      using (cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Mp3_File FROM MP3_Table", conn))
      using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          reader.Read();
          return reader["Mp3_File"] as byte[];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ya i as wat u did here in this code. i got the file read as byte[]. how to show this byte[] in aspx webpage to load the mp3 song and display it in webpage????

Comment: What do you mean by "display it", do you want to play it when the user loads the page, or do you want the user to download it?

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use a [Generic ASHX Handler](http://dotnetperls.com/ashx-handler) that retrieves the binary data and streams it to the response stream with the correct content-type header ("audio/mpeg").

If you look at the article [Displaying Images in ASP.NET Using HttpHandlers](http://aspalliance.com/1322_Displaying_Images_in_ASPNET_Using_HttpHandlers.all) then you should see the basic principle. You just need to change the content-type output.